# Time Series classification problem (how to format data?)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, classification, data-transformation

I am working on a project where a physical test over time is conducted to decide whether an object is diagnosed as class $A$ or class $B$. Typically these tests can take around 2.5-3 hours and so each timestep $t$ is recorded. $t$ is usually around one second long and so each row has a set of features at a particular second during the test. Once the test is completed, you decide whether the object is of type $A$ or $B$. Humans usually look at the time-series plot of the test to determine this classification - but I am tasked with automating it.

The issue is each CSV file for a test is approx 9000 to 11000 (2.5 to 3 multiplied by 3600 seconds in an hour) rows since the test can vary in time. The amount of features/columns are fixed. I have $N$ CSV files, which represent the time series data for one test done on one sample object (note, one sample object always gets tested once). So, my question: **Is there a way to aggregate each sample so that I can have single dataframe to train my classifier on? Or is there another approach?**

To add more clarity, I will have to make predictions on CSV files that come with inconsistent row dimensions due to the variance in testing time.

E.g.;

- csv1.shape = (8751, 1257) --> Prediction: Class $A$
- csv2.shape = (10321, 1257) --> Prediction: Class $A$
- csv3.shape = (9978, 1257) --> Prediction: Class $B$

Comment: So, in your training set, let's say there are $M$ objects. Does this mean you have $MN$ files?

Comment: @gunes one test done for one object, and so I have $N$ files for $N$ objects (made an edit in the original post).

Comment: In my opinion it is not a good idea to cast this as a classification (forced choice, premature decision) problem (see [this](https://fharrell.com/post/classification)).  Consider instead using a probability model (e.g., logistic regression) or a probability machine.  What is of most interest is estimating the _tendency_ for diagnosis class B, not to make arbitrary classifications (which are especially meaningless when the probability of class membership is around 0.5).

Comment: @FrankHarrell , sure that is a fair assessment but what would you suggest I do about the data itself so that it can actually be used as an input to, say, a logistic regression?

Comment: WIthout knowing more about your design and goals, I'd start with a simple Markov process to handle dependence between certain observations, e.g., $\Pr(Y(t) = 1 | Y(t-1), X) = \mathrm{expit}(X\beta + \gamma Y(t-1))$.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am not sure if an MP applies here because the class is decided taking into consideration all the rows of one CSV file (the time-series data of the test done on the object) which constitutes one training example. Also, I don't think you need to know about any design or goal in this case. Note I have made edits to the original post that may help clarify my problem statement some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try treating each object's time series as a function, and use tools from functional time series analysis (or functional data analysis) to analyze it.

Here is one paper [Clustering and Forecasting Multiple Functional
Time Series](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01024.pdf) which attempts to do this.

Also there is an R package for functional time series analysis [here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/shang.pdf). Possibly you could look at running principal component analysis and then classify time series based on the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be calculating summary statistics (e.g. mean, min, max, autocorrelation of varying degrees etc.) from each time series for each feature and representing an object with a long set of features.

Another option is to feed the multivariate time series into an LSTM-like architecture and train with the raw series. Although note that making LSTMs work with time series of different length is possible but may need special attention.

Comment: I have the summary stats idea noted for things I should try, however I am a bit skeptical about it as I feel that I may lose important information such as anomalous spikes in a feature at a particular time step. Could you further expand on how I can use an LSTM model to train on each time series CSV file (again, each file describes what should be a training example)? From what I understand about LSTMs using an ML framework like TensorFlow, you can only use 1 dataframe/csv as an input.

Comment: You need to prepare your data, not the same, but this link may help: https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

Comment: I am thinking of going with the approach seen in Saad's comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794867/how-to-feed-lstm-when-training-data-is-in-multiple-csv-files-of-time-series-of-d

Would like to get your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to use batch size = 1 when the frameworks you use do not support variable lengths. I don't know if things have changed in tensorflow since then. In NLP applications, I've seen a max sentence length has been set, and remaining words are padded. So it's not a bad idea all together. It might worth trying out both approaches.